# Using ColdFusion Model-Glue, how do I redirect the user back to their requested page after logging in?

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, model-glue

I have a secured event type, which will check to see if the user is logged in, and the redirect them to the login page if they're not:

```
<event-types>
    <event-type name="securedPage">
        <before>
            <broadcasts>
                <message name="CheckLogin"/>
            </broadcasts>
        </before>
        <results>
            <result name="NeedLogin" do="page.login" redirect="true"/>
        </results>
    </event-type>
</event-types>
```

The login page has a form that links to an `action.login` event handler, which will redirect to the user's homepage if login was successful, and redisplay the login page if it wasn't:

```
<event-handler name="action.login">
    <broadcasts>
        <message name="Login"/>
    </broadcasts>
    <results>
        <result name="LoggedIn" do="page.user.home" redirect="true"/>
        <result name="NotLoggedIn" do="page.login"/>
    </results>
</event-handler>
```

This code works great, but the problem I'm running into now is that it will **always** redirect to the user's homepage, even if they requested another page. Since the form posts to the **action.login** event, and the result `do` is hard-coded to `page.user.home`, how can I modify my code to keep track of which page the user originally requested and redirect them back there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the logic you use to determine if a user needs to be logged in, you can grab the current event and store it in a shared scope (like the session scope).

Then, after a successful login simply call event.forward() and pass in that value.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

here's the general idea:

1. in whatever method/code runs to 'secure' your page, if a user is not logged in, grab the url they were trying to reach and set it back to the viewstate as a variable **before** you forward them.  the CGI scope will be your friend here, particularly CGI.query_string.
2. on your sign/log in form, check for this 'returnEvent' variable in the viewstate and set it as a hidden value on your form if it exists.
3. someplace in your sign up/in process after success, check for this 'returnEvent' variable and if it exists, forward the user on.